# Get the name of an OU without having too much information in PowerShell

Tags: algorithm, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get a method to find the name of an OU dynamically.

The problem is, that the company-name-OU is always there, but the contents can change.

For example:

[image]

In this case, the company name I have to retrieve (in my script) is 'Microsoft'.

I however haven't found a method that can do this dynamically.

Since the subOU's may vary (per client, not all clients have the same OU's) it's kind of difficult to find a good method to retrieve the company-name.

I have thought about `retrieve the OU that is made by an Admin and has more than 10 objects` but the `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit`cmdlet doesn't have a parameter that sounds like `created by:`

[image]

Do I need to give up or is there some sort of way?

**EDIT**

I have tried for a workaround 'algorithmicish' kind of thing:

Since the OU will most probably contain users, I check the distinguished names of all the users which will reply

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Description -like "Member"} | Select DistinguishedName

CN=User1,OU=User,OU=Microsoft,DC=domain,DC=local
```

how could I start doing calculations (counts) of each of the OU's?

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand the question, but I can tell you that you can find the person who created the OU by selecting the "owner" like this: Get-ADOrganizationalUnit <Name of OU> -properties * | Select @{N="Owner";E={$_.nTSecurityDescriptor.owner}} You can add your "where" statement after that to filter out the admin you specifically want.  NOTE: This is true for most AD objects, if not all.

Comment: Also, you can use the "SearchBase" parameter as well as the "SearchScope" parameter on your Get-ADOrganizationalUnit cmdlet.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment but this is not working: `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | Select @{N="Owner";E={$_.nTSecurityDescriptor.owner}}`  returns 'Owner' with nothing underneath

Comment: That's because you didn't put "-properties *"

Comment: Still doesnt work but it would be my job to find out the name of the OU by checking out who created it. so this means my script can't have the parameter `Name of OU`

Comment: I ran your exact cmdlet with the -filter and -properties parameter specified and it gave me the results I expected (I have a ton of OUs).

Comment: It works but it says `Domain Admins` at every OU so this means that Active Directory doesn't seperate me when i create a new OU (it's the owner, not the creator) sadly

Comment: Are you getting the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created all your OUs, then you would get domain admins. When I run

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties * | Select @{N="Owner";E={$_.nTSecurityDescriptor}}
```

I get the attached picture (truncated)[image]

If you can determine if the OU was created after all the default OUs, you could filter on WhenCreated with a Where statement, like this:

```
$DefaultOUCreationDate = Get-ADOrganizationUnit CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local -Properties * | Select -ExpandProperty WhenCreated
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties * | Where { $_.WhenCreated -ge $DefaultOUCreationDate }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my question though since I didn't create all of the OU's (the majority of them are default generated). The `Microsoft`-OU is only created by me in the picture above in the question

Comment: I still don't really know what your question is.

Comment: Do you see the Microsoft name in the question picture? That's the name I need to catch into a variable. BUT, since the name can change of every company (Microsoft on 1 dc, Apple on other DC,...) I need to adapt a dynamic way.

Comment: While not a fool proof answer, you could use the "WhenCreated" property to be greater than the other default OUs. Something like what I'll show you in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! I'm getting close. How could I get the latest one created (its distinguished name)? That would be my only thing still needed

Comment: By piping a "Sort" after your where statement. Something like "Where... | Sort WhenCreated". You can add "-Descending" after "WhenCreated" to change the order. Then you would " Where... | Sort... | Select -first 1"